# Two questions about the vector-valued Lipschitz algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras

For a commutative Banach algebra $A$ and for any $0<\alpha<1$, let $\text{Lip}_\alpha(K,A)$ consist of all $A$-valued functions $f$ on a metric space $(K,\text d)$ with the property that $\rho_\alpha(f)<\infty$, where
$$\rho_\alpha(f):=\sup\left\{\frac{\|f(x)-f(y)\|}{\text d(x,y)^\alpha}: x,y\in X, x\neq y\right\}.$$
As in the well-known scalar-valued case, the vector-valued Lipschitz algebra
$\text{Lip}_\alpha(K,A)$ of order $\alpha$ becomes a complex Banach algebra with respect to pointwise operations, when endowed with the norm $\|\cdot\|_\alpha$ given by
$\|f\|_\alpha:=\|f\|_\infty+\rho_\alpha(f)$ for all $f\in\text{Lip}_\alpha(K,A)$.

$\text{lip}_\alpha(K,A)$ consists of all $f\in\text{Lip}_\alpha(K,A)$ for which
$$\lim_{\text d(x,y)\rightarrow0}\frac{\|f(x)-f(y)\|}{\text d(x,y)^\alpha}=0.$$
It is easily seen that $\text{lip}_\alpha(K,A)$ is a closed subalgebra of $\text{Lip}_\alpha(K,A)$. My questions are:

1. Denote by $\text{Lip}_\alpha(K)\tilde\otimes A$ the closure of $\text{Lip}_\alpha(K)\otimes A$ in $\text{Lip}_\alpha(K,A)$. Is $\text{Lip}_\alpha(K)\tilde\otimes A$ an ideal of $\text{Lip}_\alpha(K,A)$?
2. Similarly let $\text{lip}_\alpha(K)\tilde\otimes A$ be the closure of $\text{lip}_\alpha(K)\otimes A$ in $\text{lip}_\alpha(K,A)$. In [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02844254) paper it was shown that for an interval $I=[a,b]$, $\text{lip}_\alpha(I)\tilde\otimes A=\text{lip}_\alpha(I,A)$. Does the same equality hold for an arbitrary comapct metric space $K$ rather than $I$?

Comment: For number 1, notice that if $A$ us unital then so is ${\rm Lip}_\alpha(K) \overline{\otimes} A$, so it's going to be hard for this to be an ideal.

Comment: You say "the closure of ${\rm Lip}_\alpha(K) \otimes A$" --- closure in what, the norm topology I assume? Here the general advice is that the norm topology is rarely useful in Lipschitz spaces. You probably want to use the weak* topology, which will exist if $A$ is a dual space (and you choose a better norm).

Comment: @NikWeaver thank you for the comments. By the closure I mean the closure with the norm introduced in my explanation. But it is of interest for me to know the predual of this space if $A$ is a dual Banach algebra.

Comment: @NikWeaver in number 1, I'm looking for equality, is this unexpected?

Comment: You should be okay if $X$ is compact, but for noncompact $X$ there are easy counterexamples. E.g., take $X=\mathbb{N}$ with standard metric and $A = l^\infty$. The function $n \mapsto e_n$ is then Lipschitz but can't be uniformly approximated by finite linear combinations appearing in the tensor product.

Comment: @NikWeaver Great! Could you please provide me a survey which does prove this statement.

Comment: Which statement? Anyway, I think these are good exercises for you.

Comment: @NikWeaver that if $K$ is compact then we have the equality in both questions 1 and 2. I tried but I could not. This is my first encounter with Lipschitz functions, so I don't know how to start.

Comment: Find an $\epsilon$-net and use a Lipschitz partition of unity.

Comment: @NikWeaver: I did that, but this proves that $Lip(K)\otimes A$ is uniformly dense in $Lip(K,A)$, not w.r.t norm $\|f\|_\alpha=\|f\|_\infty+\rho_\alpha(f)$.

Comment: Oh, you're right. It's false even if $K$ is compact. Take $K = [0,1]$ and $A = l^\infty$ and define $f: K \to A$ by setting $f(2^{-n}) = 2^{-n}e_n$ and extending linearly between the points $2^{-n}$. That shouldn't be approximable in Lipschitz norm by anything in the tensor product.